# Is $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y-x^2))$ the same as $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x])$ ?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y-x^2)$. We have that $$\operatorname{Spec}(R)=\{(0),(x-a,y-a^2),(y-x^2)\}. $$
But if we consider the quotient ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y-x^2) \simeq \mathbb{C}[x]$. But $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x])=\{(0),(x-a)\}$. So we have isomorphic rings that have different $\operatorname{Spec}$... How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Er, $\{0\}$ isn't an ideal of the quotient since it doesn't contain $(y-x^2)$. Did you actually mean the zero ideal of the ring (which you already listed?)

Comment: @YACP The zero ideal of the ring in question is $(y-x^2)/(y-x^2)$, which he was apparently trying to list separately as "$(x-y^2)$" He should pick one of them, at any rate.

Answer (score 4):

$(x-a,y-a^2)\equiv(x-a)$ since $y-a^2\equiv x^2-a^2\equiv(x-a)(x+a)$ in the quotient.

Deleting the $(0)$ (which looks rather like a typo) from the first list, your two lists match.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start describing $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb C[X,Y])$: $(0)$, the prime ideals of height one (these are generated by irreducible polynomials), and the maximal ideals which are of the form $(X-a,Y-b)$.

The prime ideals of $R=\mathbb C[X,Y]/(Y-X^2)$ are of the form $P/(Y-X^2)$, where $P$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb C[X,Y]$ containing $Y-X^2$. Now let's choose from the prime ideals of $\mathbb C[X,Y]$ those which contains $Y-X^2$: $(Y-X^2)$ which is the only one of height $1$, and the maximal ideals of the form $(X-a,Y-a^2)$. In the end we find $$\operatorname{Spec}(R)=\{(Y-X^2)/(Y-X^2)=(0), (X-a,Y-a^2)/(Y-X^2)\}.$$ If one denotes the residue classes of $X$ and $Y$ modulo $(Y-X^2)$ by $x$, respectively $y$, then we can write $\operatorname{Spec}(R)=\{(0), (x-a,y-a^2)\}$. Furthermore, since $y=x^2$ we have $(x-a,y-a^2)=(x-a, x^2-a^2)=(x-a)$, so $\operatorname{Spec}(R)=\{(0), (x-a)\}$.

Comment: But rschwieb in his comment said that there isn't $(0)$...

Comment: @ArthurStuart The thing is that you did not write the first spectrum very well. You should write a list of ideals of the quotient ring, but it looks like you listed ideals of $\Bbb C[x,y]$ instead. The list should be $\{(x-y^2)/(x-y^2)\}\cup\{(x-a)/(x-y^2)\mid a\in \Bbb C\} $. *Those* are ideals of the quotient ring, the first one being zero in the quotient ring.

Comment: YACP's final answer is fine too, he has just chosen to write the spectrum using the images of the ideals I wrote in the quotient. Some authors use overlines to make it clear that they are ideals of the quotient ring like this: $\overline{(0)},\overline{(x-a)}$. By writing both $\{0\}$ and $(x-y^2)$ in your original answer you were being unclear, because they both seem to indicate the zero ideal in the quotient.

Answer (score -2):

There is no problem: the element $a$ in your description of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ can be any complex number and different $a$'s lead to different prime ideals. Hence the spectrum is infinite, as well as the spectrum of the polynomial ring.